# How to mention a map/dictionary attribute in a condition expression with put_item in dynamodb

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a dynamo table with costcenter as hash key and want to add new team details in single db item/entry if team name does not exist.

[image: sample image of db item that shows addition of teams]

my code is executed in lambda.

```
import json
import boto3


dynamodb_res = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-south-1')
table=dynamodb_res.Table('sampletable')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    def add_team():
        table.put_item(
        Item={
            'COSTCENTER': event['costcenter'],
            'Teams': {
                 event['teamName']: {
                     "EMAIL": event['email'],
                     "GROUP": event['group']     
                }
            }
        },
        ConditionExpression= "attribute_not_exists(Teams[event['teamName']])"
        )
    add_team()
```

parameter `event['teamname']` contains team name information.parameters are in configure test event console of lambda.

My params:

```
{
  "teamName": "team1",
  "costcenter": "0000",
  "email": "sample@samplename.com",
  "group": "devops"
}
```

'team1' team needs to be added only if it's not there.
I get below error after running code.

```
"errorType": "ClientError",
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: Invalid ConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: \"event\", near: \"[event[\""
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ConditionExpression` you can supply static parameters or so called expression attribute parametes for replacement, like this:

- `attribute_not_exists(Teams.team1)` (static)
- `attribute_not_exists(:team)` (expression attribute)

In latter case you will need to provide separate `ExpressionAttributeValues`param to your boto3 call.

Here's doc on that, which is referenced in boto3 documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

In your case I would just try to expand the name of parameter using an `f-string`:

`ConditionExpression=f"attribute_not_exists(Teams.{[event['teamName']})"`